# How to find file compression or obfuscation type

Tags: unpacking, deobfuscation, decryption

The program I'm trying to decompile uses several supporting files:

- somesound.mp3
- someimage.jpg
- etc..

The files are all located in the file system, not embedded into the exe. The files are used at runtime for the game images and sounds.

If I try and open one of the mp3s or jpgs directly windows will give me an error, the files are obviously packed/encrypted/obfuscated/compressed.

**How can I determine the obfuscation type of the files?**

I have determined that the first 4 bytes are the same in each file, 43 46 31 30 *(CF10 in ASCII)*. Maybe this information would be useful.

Comment: If those bytes are *added* to the original files, that's already enough to make them unusable with regular software. Check what's directly after them; does that data look like a JPEG, MP3, etc.?

Comment: @Jongware No, there's no normal JPEG data after CF10. I found this question, it explains that CF10 means compression factor of 10 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113641/file-format-of-cf10-jpg

Comment: What OS you are using?

Comment: @nrz using windows 8

Comment: Why don't you link a few example files or show us more than just the first four bytes. Somebody with a lot of experience with file formats might be able to spot the encoding.

Comment: @Till I did consider linking files, but they are not my property and obviously not open source. I do not want to reveal the application that I am decompiling.

Comment: Then besides simply looking at the files, the only option I can see is looking at the decoding part of that application, tried using a debugger yet?

Answer (score 7):

You can give a try to [binwalk](http://code.google.com/p/binwalk/). This tool is able to do a wild guess about the encryption/compression routine used, with the `-BE` option.

Answer (score 1):

(After *finally* being able to examine 2 examples)

They are regular files, obfuscated with a simple XOR encoding. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442162/decryption-of-png-and-jpg-files for a longer description.

The file extension may or may not be the original one.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the response, looks good! I will test tomorrow and see if it works for my files as well.